# Repair Microsoft common targets file

Tags: .net

Since I "somehow" accidently edited the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file because it was somehow opened in an existing VS project...

in path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

I can not build any NEW VS 2010 project anymore because all the default .NET assemblies under the references show a yellow triangle warning that the assemblies are missing.

It doesnt matter wether this is a winforms or console project.

The odd thing is even for a new .NET 3.5 project the build fails.

How can I repair this broken file?

Comment: Is this for an existing project or did you create a new one and this is happening from the beginning?

Comment: I don't think you screwed up the targets file. I think the targets file is saying it cannot find the resources it requires. HAve you tried reparing visual studio and the .net framework?

Comment: Did you try repair the .NET installation?

Comment: If you want to repair go to Programs in windows -> uninstall \ change and select change. You should be prompted at some point to repair. I would repair both VS and .Net.

Comment: Copy it from another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Will that have side effects? Are there machine dependent data in the targets file?

Comment: I would have recommended copying if that was the case.